# i want to add the elements of array but from index 1-5, this is giving me error

Tags: arrays

```
main()
{
    int ar[5][9];
    int a,b,b1,sum=0;
    printf("St ID\tC1 marks\tC2 marks\tC3 marks\tC4 marks\tC5 marks\ttotal marks\tobt marks\tpercentage\n");
    for(a=0;a<5;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<9;b++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&ar[a][b]);
            switch(b)
            {
                case 7:
                    printf("%d\t",100);
                    
            
                    for(b1=1;b1<5;b++)
                    {
                        sum=sum+ar[b1];
                    }
                    printf("%d\t",sum);
                
                    printf("%d\t",(sum/100)*100);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code which is giving me error. Plz help. I am trying to print a mark sheet for several students. i take the input from b 1 to b 5 because i first have to add them and then find the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the third for loop you started the loop from 1-5 and it reads only 4 element of your array

```
main()
{
int ar[5][9];
int a,b,b1,sum=0;
printf("St ID\tC1 marks\tC2 marks\tC3 marks\tC4 marks\tC5 marks\ttotal marks\tobt marks\tpercentage\n");
for(a=0;a<5;a++)
{
    for(b=0;b<9;b++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ar[a][b]);
        switch(b)
        {
            case 7:
                printf("%d\t",100);
                
               //here is the change 
                for(b1=0;b1<5;b++)
                {
                    sum=sum+ar[b1];
                }
                printf("%d\t",sum);
            
                printf("%d\t",(sum/100)*100);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}